# ATMEGA2560 died inside a arcade game circuit

Tags: arduino-mega, hardware, atmega2560

I am building arcade game with 10 player buttons (5 for each player) and one start button. All buttons have build in LED inside. Player buttons has LED for 12V and start button has led for 5V. I am using ATMEGA2560 pro boar. I have also 4 TM1637 displays (two for each player) showing time and score. I am using 12V adapter. This is my schematic:

[image: schematics]

This is test code which I had:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TM1637Display.h>

#define BTN_A1_PIN 16
#define BTN_A2_PIN 18
#define BTN_A3_PIN 28
#define BTN_A4_PIN 26
#define BTN_A5_PIN 47

#define BTN_B1_PIN 44
#define BTN_B2_PIN 36
#define BTN_B3_PIN 39
#define BTN_B4_PIN 46
#define BTN_B5_PIN 37

#define LED_A1_PIN 13
#define LED_A2_PIN 17
#define LED_A3_PIN 11
#define LED_A4_PIN 15
#define LED_A5_PIN 19

#define LED_B1_PIN 25
#define LED_B2_PIN 27
#define LED_B3_PIN 23
#define LED_B4_PIN 21
#define LED_B5_PIN 29

#define BTN_START_PIN 32
#define LED_START_PIN 35

#define DISPLAY_A_SCORE_CLK 20
#define DISPLAY_A_SCORE_DIO 10

#define DISPLAY_A_TIME_CLK 40
#define DISPLAY_A_TIME_DIO 43

#define DISPLAY_B_SCORE_CLK 42
#define DISPLAY_B_SCORE_DIO 33

#define DISPLAY_B_TIME_CLK 34
#define DISPLAY_B_TIME_DIO 38

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t btnIn;
  uint8_t ledOut;
} btn_t;

btn_t btn[] = {
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_A1_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_A1_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_A2_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_A2_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_A3_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_A3_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_A4_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_A4_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_A5_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_A5_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_B1_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_B1_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_B2_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_B2_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_B3_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_B3_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_B4_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_B4_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_B5_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_B5_PIN,
    },
    {
        .btnIn = BTN_START_PIN,
        .ledOut = LED_START_PIN,
    },
};

TM1637Display displayAScore(DISPLAY_A_SCORE_CLK, DISPLAY_A_SCORE_DIO);
TM1637Display displayATime(DISPLAY_A_TIME_CLK, DISPLAY_A_TIME_DIO);
TM1637Display displayBScore(DISPLAY_B_SCORE_CLK, DISPLAY_B_SCORE_DIO);
TM1637Display displayBTime(DISPLAY_B_TIME_CLK, DISPLAY_B_TIME_DIO);

void setup()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
  {
    pinMode(btn[i].btnIn, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(btn[i].ledOut, OUTPUT);
  }
  displayAScore.setBrightness(0x0f);
  displayATime.setBrightness(0x0f);
  displayBScore.setBrightness(0x0f);
  displayBTime.setBrightness(0x0f);

  displayAScore.showNumberDec(1111, false);
  displayATime.showNumberDec(2222, false);
  displayBScore.showNumberDec(3333, false);
  displayBTime.showNumberDec(4444, false);
}

void loop()
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 11; i++)
  {
    if(0 == digitalRead(btn[i].btnIn))
    {
      digitalWrite(btn[i].ledOut, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(btn[i].ledOut, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what it looks like inside:

[image: arcade box inside]

[image: arcade box front]

The problem is **ATMEGA2560** just burned. I was testing it firstly without TM1637 (they were connected to power but I did not use lib for them at that time) and it was working okay (buttons were lighting up upon pressing).

Then I added lib for TM1637 to code and for 2 seconds I saw "1111" "2222" ... so on as it is in code, so there is no bad connection. But after 2 seconds it started buzzing (probably linear regulator temp protection was kicking in) and ATMEGA just burned.

Now when I plug 12V in it MCU gets hot pretty fast. I can measure 5V on the linear regulator so it is not shorted. I had always connected only 12V and no power from USB. I know my wires are not the shortest but I would not expect that MCU dies. Could you help please? I don't want to plug the next 20€ chip just to see another expensive smoke.

Comment: either something is miswired, or a component is not what you think it is ... maybe the buttons have an internal connection between the switch and the indicator LED

Comment: @jsotola thanks for answer. I double checked every connection and it was correct. No, buttons are not connected with LEDs

Comment: The 5V pin on the board probably isn't a good place to pull power for the displays.  I'm sure that's more than it can supply.  Ideally they should have their own power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fried it because you broke rule #1: "A Power Supply the Arduino is NOT!". Your displays can pull 320 Ma in themselves. That is over 2 watts of power before anything else. When you get a new one purchase a buck converter and power the LEDs with the 5V output of that, use the 12V to feed it. As I understand it The suggested maximum power dissipation for the Mega regulator is 1 Watt. So with 12V into the regulator the max current is about 140 mA (1W / (12V - 5V)), This does not count your LEDs.

Comment: I was counting on the protection circuit of the regulator, these linear ones use to have it. But is it strange why ATMEGA burned, but regulator is outputting 5V. I used separate supply for ATMEGA and displays and now it is working. Thanks for answer.